# Inner join in hibernate from two classes

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join, inner-join

I have these 2 domain classes:
Staff.java

```html
package it.jack.fdd.domain;
// Generated 9-dic-2016 17.38.23 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1.Final

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;

/**
 * Staff generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "staff", catalog = "fdd_dbproducts")
public class Staff implements java.io.Serializable {

 private Integer idstaff;
 private StaffType staffType;
 private String name;
 private String surname;
 private Date birthDate;
 private String phone;
 private boolean gender;
 private Boolean working;
 private StaffLogin staffLogin;
 private Set<RtStaffDispenser> rtStaffDispensers = new HashSet<RtStaffDispenser>(0);

 public Staff() {
 }

 public Staff(StaffType staffType, String name, String surname, Date birthDate, String phone, boolean gender) {
  this.staffType = staffType;
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.birthDate = birthDate;
  this.phone = phone;
  this.gender = gender;
 }

 public Staff(StaffType staffType, String name, String surname, Date birthDate, String phone, boolean gender,
   Boolean working, StaffLogin staffLogin, Set<RtStaffDispenser> rtStaffDispensers) {
  this.staffType = staffType;
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.birthDate = birthDate;
  this.phone = phone;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.working = working;
  this.staffLogin = staffLogin;
  this.rtStaffDispensers = rtStaffDispensers;
 }

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

 @Column(name = "idstaff", unique = true, nullable = false)
 public Integer getIdstaff() {
  return this.idstaff;
 }

 public void setIdstaff(Integer idstaff) {
  this.idstaff = idstaff;
 }

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 //metto EAGER al posto di LAZY altrimenti mi da errore 500 e per quanto riguarda la chiave esterna.
 @JoinColumn(name = "fkstaff_type_staff", nullable = false)
 public StaffType getStaffType() {
  return this.staffType;
 }

 public void setStaffType(StaffType staffType) {
  this.staffType = staffType;
 }

 @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
 public String getName() {
  return this.name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false, length = 45)
 public String getSurname() {
  return this.surname;
 }

 public void setSurname(String surname) {
  this.surname = surname;
 }

 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 @Column(name = "birth_date", nullable = false, length = 0)
 public Date getBirthDate() {
  return this.birthDate;
 }

 public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
  this.birthDate = birthDate;
 }

 @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false, length = 45)
 public String getPhone() {
  return this.phone;
 }

 public void setPhone(String phone) {
  this.phone = phone;
 }

 @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false)
 public boolean isGender() {
  return this.gender;
 }

 public void setGender(boolean gender) {
  this.gender = gender;
 }

 @Column(name = "working")
 public Boolean getWorking() {
  return this.working;
 }

 public void setWorking(Boolean working) {
  this.working = working;
 }

 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "staff")
 public StaffLogin getStaffLogin() {
  return this.staffLogin;
 }

 public void setStaffLogin(StaffLogin staffLogin) {
  this.staffLogin = staffLogin;
 }

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "staff")
 @JsonIgnore
 public Set<RtStaffDispenser> getRtStaffDispensers() {
  return this.rtStaffDispensers;
 }

 public void setRtStaffDispensers(Set<RtStaffDispenser> rtStaffDispensers) {
  this.rtStaffDispensers = rtStaffDispensers;
 }

}
```

RtStaffDispenser.java

```html
package it.jack.fdd.domain;
// Generated 30-nov-2016 0.17.09 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1.Final

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * RtStaffDispenser generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "rt_staff_dispenser", catalog = "fdd_dbproducts")
public class RtStaffDispenser implements java.io.Serializable {

 private Integer idrtStaffDispenser;
 private Dispenser dispenser;
 private Staff staff;

 public RtStaffDispenser() {
 }

 public RtStaffDispenser(Dispenser dispenser, Staff staff) {
  this.dispenser = dispenser;
  this.staff = staff;
 }

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

 @Column(name = "idrt_staff_dispenser", unique = true, nullable = false)
 public Integer getIdrtStaffDispenser() {
  return this.idrtStaffDispenser;
 }

 public void setIdrtStaffDispenser(Integer idrtStaffDispenser) {
  this.idrtStaffDispenser = idrtStaffDispenser;
 }

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "fkdispenser_rtsdispenser", nullable = false)
 public Dispenser getDispenser() {
  return this.dispenser;
 }

 public void setDispenser(Dispenser dispenser) {
  this.dispenser = dispenser;
 }

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "fkstaff_rtsdispenser", nullable = false)
 public Staff getStaff() {
  return this.staff;
 }

 public void setStaff(Staff staff) {
  this.staff = staff;
 }

}
```

who have this relationship in the database:

[image]

I want to make a query in hibernate that shows all the elements of `Staff` INNER JOIN `RtStaffDispenser` ON `Staff.idstaff = RtStaffDispenser.idRtsdispenser`.
How I can do it? I know `SQL INNER JOIN`, but I don't know `HIBERNATE INNER JOIN`

JUNIT error:

```html
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [from it.jack.fdd.domain.Staff inner join RtStaffDispenser on Staff.idstaff = RtStaffDispenser.idrtStaffDispenser]
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
 at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
 at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
 at it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.StaffDaoImpl.getAllA(StaffDaoImpl.java:95)
 at it.jack.fdd.tests.StaffDaoImplTest.testGetAllA(StaffDaoImplTest.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: where is your Rtsdispenser in rt_staff_dispenser bean ?.You can use inner join on Staff.idstaff = RtStaffDispenser.idrtStaffDispenser, not on Staff.idstaff = RtStaffDispenser.Rtsdispenser.

Comment: It does not work anyway

Comment: JUNIT shows this error: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [from it.jack.fdd.domain.Staff inner join RtStaffDispenser on Staff.idstaff = RtStaffDispenser.idrtStaffDispenser]

Comment: It would be great if you can  provide me the whole error log, I just want to know about when it's throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in this way:

"select s from RtStaffDispenser r inner join r.staff s"